# Отобрать строки из 3х таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы. В одной таблице есть продукты с категориями, в другой продукты с картинками. 
Т.е. категории с картинками могу объединить через продукты. Но мне нужна только картинка первого продукта. Как отфильтровать остальные?

Comment: Есть три таблицы: продукты с категориями, продукты с картинками и третья (какая?). Да и условие можно бы поконкретней задать. А так может подойдёт:

     select a.prod, a.pic, b.cat from tab1 a join
       (select min(prod) as prod, cat from tab2 group by cat) b on a.prod = b.prod;

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вы можете использовать **JOIN** для выборки из двух или более таблиц.

Примеры использования на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44807/) или в [оф. документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: не совсем. Джойном я пользоваться умею. Как с помощью Where или какого-либо условного оператора в mysql показать, что мне необходим только первое совпадение каждого товара?